# Interpretation of regression coefficient, which is dlog-log variable?

Tags: econometrics, interpretation, regression-coefficients

Can anyone suss out the interpretation of beta here:

D.log(gdp) = alpha + beta(log(military expenditure %)

Where D.log(gdp) = growth of GDP (first difference of log(GDP)

Would it be:

A 1% point increase in military expenditure is associated with a beta% point change in the growth of GDP?

OR

A 1% increase in military expenditure is associated with a beta % change in the growth of GDP?

OR neither?

N.B. Also what implication does the underlying variable military expenditure have being a %, wouldn't that make the interpretation a percentage point?

Thanks 
Labib

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+interpret+log+answers%3A1 for more answers.

Comment: @MatthewGunn no its for a paper trying to measure the effect that corruption has indirectly via military spending, however i have recently changed specification of the model from where the independent variables were first differenced to simple logs, as such i have confused myself. Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: @whuber i have looked and havent been able to find something which interprets a dlog-log regression coefficient

Comment: If I'm reading what you wrote correctly, a military expenditure increase as a share of GDP of 1% (eg. from 10% of the budget to 10.1%) is associated with a $\beta$ * 1% increase in the GDP growth rate. (You almost certainly don't want to give this a causal interpretation.)

Comment: @MatthewGunn just to clarify - when you say a 1% increase in ((military expenditure share of GDP) <- which is already in percentage) is associated with a β  * 1% increase in the GDP growth rate. You mean that the 10% -> 10.1%, is as the 0.1% increase is 1% of 10%? correct? Sorry for that confusing interpretation. Also just for my future understanding why is it not percentage point/ when would it be? Thanks again!

Comment: @MatthewGunn also why would you not give this causal interpretation?

Comment: $\log(.101)−\log(.1)\approx.01$. You would not give this a causal (right side causes left side) interpretation because you've got reverse causation, confounding, etc.... Clearly GDP growth affects the budget. When I spend a larger percentage of my income on diamonds, my income grows faster? That's quite possible, but buying diamonds almost certainly doesn't raise my income.

Comment: @MatthewGunn ah i see, reverse causality - i am trying to account for that using a system gmm estimator. Thank you Matthew.